# unable to parse template class error message android studio

Tags: java, android, class, ide, intellij-14

I'm having a really weird problem with my AS when creating a new Java Class; I've already tried other solutions in stack and android developers page, but nothing seems to work (reinstalling, class template, vm options and invalidate cache).

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVQEZ.png)

Does anyone figure out what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Hi chicoRafa, the error is asking if you missed the braces In your class. see if that helps.

Comment: Hi, i've tried that and didn't work; finally I rewritten the class template in project and global and seems to work. Thanks for your advice whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

As i commented before, the problem was solved by rewriting the Java Class template in the project and global instance of it.

I don't really know why it didn't work before, but if someone is in that position just try again with this method.